Experience Cloud page - LiveChat Integration
I would like to add LiveChat to Experience Cloud page. The problem is that they require adding the code before the /body tag.
Here is the guide:
https://www.livechat.com/help/setting-up-livechat-on-your-website/
<script>
  window.__lc = window.__lc || {};
  window.__lc.license = 0000000;
  ;(function(n,t,c){function i(n){return e._h?e._h.apply(null,n):e._q.push(n)}var e={_q:[],_h:null,_v:"2.0",on:function(){i(["on",c.call(arguments)])},once:function(){i(["once",c.call(arguments)])},off:function(){i(["off",c.call(arguments)])},get:function(){if(!e._h)throw new Error("[LiveChatWidget] You can't use getters before load.");return i(["get",c.call(arguments)])},call:function(){i(["call",c.call(arguments)])},init:function(){var n=t.createElement("script");n.async=!0,n.type="text/javascript",n.src="https://cdn.livechatinc.com/tracking.js",t.head.appendChild(n)}};!n.__lc.asyncInit&&e.init(),n.LiveChatWidget=n.LiveChatWidget||e}(window,document,[].slice))
</script>
<noscript><a href="https://www.livechat.com/chat-with/000000/" rel="nofollow">Chat with us</a>, powered by <a href="https://www.livechat.com/?welcome" rel="noopener nofollow" target="_blank">LiveChat</a></noscript>

for now I'm using Static Resources and displaying it in an iFrame. But I have a problem with the size because it does not adjust to the displayed content. Therefore I would prefer not to use iFrame.
Maybe you have an idea how to dynamically change the size of the iFrame to the content or adding the code before the /body tag
